# Spring @Scheduled fixedDelay is not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have 2 jobs running asynchronously one which triggers everymin and another with a fixed delay.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=30000)
    public void runJob() {
        try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution=jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);
        LOGGER.info(execution.getExitStatus());}
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                throw new SystemException("Scheduler ERROR :: Error coocured during Job run "+e);
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                LOGGER.error("Scheduler ERROR :: Error coocured during Job run "+e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void runJob2() {
        try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution execution=jobLauncher.run(job2,jobParameters);
         LOGGER.info(execution.getExitStatus());}
        catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                throw new SystemException("ERROR:: Exception occured"+e);
            } catch (SystemException e1) {
                LOGGER.error("ERROR:: JOB Launching exception happened"+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

as fixedDelay says "the duration between the end of last execution and the start of next execution is fixed" but for me its triggering with a fixed delay between the starts of last and next execution.

```
2018-05-11 **12:48:00.016**  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-5] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=systemStartJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1526023080016}]
2018-05-11 12:48:00.016  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-5] org.sapient.t1automation.SystemListener  : Intercepting system Job Execution - Before Job!
2018-05-11 12:48:00.017  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-5] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [systemStartStep]
.
.
.
.
2018-05-11 **12:48:24.721**  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-6] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=sendMailJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1526023104706}]
2018-05-11 12:48:24.737  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-6] org.sapient.t1automation.MailListener    : Intercepting Job Excution - Before Job!
2018-05-11 12:48:24.737  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-6] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [sendMailStep1]
.
.
.
2018-05-11 12:48:44.533  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-6] org.sapient.t1automation.MailListener    : Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!
2018-05-11 12:48:44.533  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-6] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=sendMailJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{time=1526023104706}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2018-05-11 12:48:45.001  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-3] o.s.t.service.mail.MailReader            : Mail:: Mails to process. 1
2018-05-11 12:48:45.017  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-3] org.sapient.t1automation.MailListener    : Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!
2018-05-11 12:48:45.017  INFO 2112 --- [ taskExecutor-3] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=sendMailJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{time=1526023044672}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

here the time between start of 2 executions is 30s instead of between end of last and start of next execution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the execution time of you code. It may be possible your code executes within a second, hence you cant see the time difference.

Sample example:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
private void test() {

    System.out.println("test -> " + new Date());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

> Output

```
test -> Fri May 11 13:45:35 IST 2018
test -> Fri May 11 13:45:40 IST 2018
test -> Fri May 11 13:45:45 IST 2018
test -> Fri May 11 13:45:51 IST 2018
test -> Fri May 11 13:45:56 IST 2018
```

Here you can see, difference between every print is 5 seconds instead of 3 seconds.

For debugging, you can add logs at start and end of the code. Also, Thread.sleep() for delay.

Comment: in the logs completed time is also there by that only im able to say that next execution is starting after 30s after last execution is started